# Does there exist $a,b,c\in \mathbb{R}$ s.t. $\cos(t)\sin(t)t = a \exp \left\{ \left( \frac{\cos(t)+\sin(t)+t-b}{c} \right)^2 \right\}$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, curves, parametric

Suppose that we have two functions of a shared parameter $t$:

$$x(t) = \cos(t)+\sin(t)+t$$
$$y(t) = \cos(t)\sin(t)t$$

When I plot $x(t)$ against $y(t)$ I get the sense that the graph might be 'half-of-a-Gaussian' function:

[image]

Setting this up algebraically, we have:

$\cos(t)\sin(t)t = a \exp \left\{ -\left( \frac{\cos(t)+\sin(t)+t-b}{c} \right)^2 \right\}$

I have tried tinkering around with parameters in Desmos manually, but no luck. It gets a little tricky that you have to consider 3 parameters at once. I found that `a,b,c == 0.46, 2.5, 0.73` was pretty close, but not visually perfect.

[image]

Does there exist $a,b,c\in \mathbb{R}$ s.t. $\cos(t)\sin(t)t = a \exp \left\{ -\left( \frac{\cos(t)+\sin(t)+t-b}{c} \right)^2 \right\}$?

---

@Joe pointed out that this equality cannot hold for all $t$ b/c the LHS alternates in sign whereas the RHS does not. Instead, there appears to be a restricted interval of $x(t)$ where the equality might hold. This tacitly means that there are certain intervals over $t$ for which the equality holds.

If it is still tractable, please consider my question over these certain intervals of $t$.

Comment: For only one specific value of $t$?

Comment: @Joe Thank you for asking for clarifications. For all $t$.

Comment: If $t$ varies over all real numbers, then the LHS will alternate signs but the RHS will not.

Comment: @Joe You're right! I overlooked that. Desmos just plots where it is defined I guess.

Comment: I need to rethink the question. I will edit when I have reformulated it in my head.

Comment: I'm not sure what your goal is, but perhaps you want it over an interval.

Comment: @joe Thank you for the suggestion. I would like the solution for the limited intervals in which the putative equality might hold.

Answer (score 2):

Looks can be deceiving. You did not plot the function over a long enough interval for $t$! If you plot the function with $t \in [0, 12 \pi]$ you obtain a plot like this:

[image]

This is obviously not an exponential function.